# BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

Is `BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP` really supported starting SQL Server 2016 as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions?view=sql-server-2016) states? I am using SQL Server 2017 (14.0.2027.2) Enterprise Edition and when I execute:

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [test]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [test]
ADD (BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP)
```

I receive an error:

```
Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Keyword or statement option 'BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Same query succeeds for SQL Server 2019.

Comment: You are running an almost unpatched RTM version of SQL Server 2017. Have you tried to update the instance to one of the latest CUs?

Comment: @RogerWolf Most likely not, it's dev machine, but the documentation clearly states it's supported starting from SQL Server 2016, not SQL Server 2017 CU xx, so that's what actually confuses me. Looks like documentation glitch to me.

Comment: possibly, or a bug in RTM. Have seen my fair share of them, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a [documentation bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/5154).